# Cannot select from website redundant drop-downs or update

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am new at VBA and trying to automate a website menu selection using VBA. The website has a few drop-downs that I have not been able to successful change or update. I have tried earlier suggestions from this website, but have not had any success. The other values on the site can be filled in .value = xxx, but the drop-downs are a bit harder.
The website is (https://worldfreightrates.com/en/freight).
The HTML for the section is this:

```
<div id="fcl" style="display: block;">
     <p>Container Type</p>
   <div class="dk_container dk_theme_default" id="dk_container_containerLoadType"tabindex=""style="display: block;">
     <a class="dk_toggle">
        <span class="dk_label">20 FT</span>
       </a>
     <div class="dk_options" style="top: 29px;">
       <ul class="dk_options_inner">
         <li class="dk_option_current">
           <a data-dk-dropdown-value="20">20 FT</a></li>
         <li class=""> 
           <a data-dk-dropdown-value="40">40 FT</a></li>
         <li class=""> 
           <a data-dk-dropdown-value="45">45 FT</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
  <select name="value" class="dropkick" id="containerLoadType" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="20">20 FT</option>
                    <option value="40" selected="true">40 FT</option>
                    <option value="45">45 FT</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

````
     Here is my code:
     ```
     Option Explicit
     Public Sub dropdown()

     Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

     Set ws = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")

     Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

     Dim doc As HTMLDivision
     Dim htmldc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

     Dim x As Long, y As Long

     Dim ur As String

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     On Error Resume Next

     ur = "https://worldfreightrates.com/en/freight"

     ie.Visible = True
     ie.navigate ur
     x = 0
     y = 0

     Do While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
     Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
     While ie.Busy
     DoEvents
     Wend

     Set htmldc = ie.document

     Dim dk_open As Object
     Dim cont As Object
     Set cont = htmldc.getElementById("dk_container_containerloadtype")
     Dim label As Object
     Dim toggle As Object
     Set toggle = cont.getElementsByClassName("dk_toggle")
     Toggle.item.click
     'toggle.item.click opens dropdown menu
     toggle.Item.Click
     toggle.Item(0).Value = "20 FT"
     toggle.selectedIndex = 0
     Set label = htmldc.getElementsByClassName("dk_label")

     Dim opts As Object, opt As Object
     Set opts = htmldc.getElementById("containerLoadType")

     opts.Item(0).Value = "0"
     opts.Item(0).FireEvent ("onChange")

     For Each opt In opts
     Debug.Print (opt.innerText)
     If InStr(opt.innerText, "20") Then
     y = x
     opts.Item(0).selectedIndex = y
     opt.Item(0).Click
     opt.initEvent "change", True, False
     opt.Selected = True
     label.Value = opt.innerText
     label.selectedIndex = y
     End If
     x = x + 1
     Next opt

     Dim dk_opts As Object, dk_opt As Object

     Set dk_opts = htmldc.getElementById 
     ("dk_container_containerLoadType").getElementsByTagName("li 
      ")

     For Each dk_opt In dk_opts

     'Debug.Print (dk_opt.innerText)
     If InStr(dk_opt.innerText, "20") Then
     'below items do not change selection
     dk_opt.Item(0).selectedindex = y
     dk_opt.Click
     dk_opt.Selected = True
     End If

     Next dk_opt

     handler:

     ie.Quit
     Set ie = Nothing
     Exit Sub

     ie.Quit
     Set ie = Nothing
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     End Sub
     ```
````

The problem:
I can open the menu, and from there I loop through the option tables until the desired option is reached. After that I am not sure how to put the value into the drop-down menu or how to update the webpage once the value is selected. There is no errors that appear, the value is just not selected from what I can tell.
I have tried using the following:

````
    ```
    opts.Item(0).Value = "0"

    opts.Item(0).FireEvent ("onChange")

    opts.selectedindex= 0  

    opts.selection = true 
    ```
````

Can anyone please point in the right direction or tell me if my code is faulty? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Only the `select` element has a `selectedIndex` - individual options do not.

Comment: The page does not run in IE. You can't set any "Commodity" from the dropdown. It always remains on "Select Commodity". Try it manualy. It does not work. In his answer Josh Pachner already points to selenium or python as possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Not the Best Solution but I Hope this helps
Please refer the attached image for the input sheet, from where the fields will be populated.

[Input Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymmo3.png)

I am also a Newbie so there might be better and shorter way of doing things

Here is the Code -

```
Sub World_Freight_Rates()

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True 'Let's see the browser window

ie.navigate "https://worldfreightrates.com/en/freight"

Do While ie.Busy 'We need to wait until the page has loaded
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lr
Var = Cells(x, 1).Value

'Get Window ID for IE so we can set it as activate window
    HWNDSrc = ie.HWND
'Set IE as Active Window
    SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set OP = ie.document.getElementById("fromNameOcean")
    OP.Focus
    'SendKeys "Portland", True 'Type Out
    OP.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & x).Value 'Set the textbox value Range

'Wait for the Dropdown to Load
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True 'Hit Down Arrow
Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hit "ENTER", to make it work IE window should be active & up top

Set DP = ie.document.getElementById("toNameOcean")
    DP.Focus
    'SendKeys "New York", True 'Type Out
    DP.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & x).Value 'Set the textbox value Range

'Wait for the Dropdown to Load
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True 'Hit Down Arrow
Application.SendKeys "~", True 'Hit "ENTER", to make it work IE window should be active & up top

Set SC = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("dk_toggle") 'Id("dk_container_commodityNameOcean")
    'MsgBox SC(0).innerText
    SC(17).Click
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Agriculture (Fruits and Vegetables)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Apparel" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Automobiles & Motorcycles" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Automobile & Motorcycle Parts" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Arts & Crafts" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Beauty & Personal Care" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Chemicals" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Computer Hardware & Software" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Construction Equipment" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Construction Materials" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Consumer Electronics" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Electrical Equipment & Supplies" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Electronic Components & Supplies" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Fashion Accessories" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Bottled Beverages" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Bottled Products (Non-beverages)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Food (Perishable)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Food (Non-Perishable) i.e. Cereals and Grains" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Food (Frozen)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Food (Frozen Meat)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Furniture (New Branded)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Furniture (Used)" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Hardware" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Health & Medical Supplies" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Home Appliances" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Home & Garden" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Household Goods" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Lights & Lighting" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Luggage, Bags & Cases" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Mechanical & Fabrication Parts" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Machinery" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Measurement & Analysis Instruments" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Minerals & Metallurgy" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Office & School Supplies" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Packaging & Printing" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Rubber & Plastics" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Security & Protection" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Shoes & Accessories" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Sports & Entertainment" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Telecommunications" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Textiles & Leather Products" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Timepieces, Jewelry, Eyewear" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Tools" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Toys & Hobbies" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "Transportation" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
    End If

Set CV = ie.document.getElementById("commodityValueOcean")
    CV.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & x).Value

Set CT = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("dk_toggle")
    CT(18).Click
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & x).Value = "20" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{UP}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & x).Value = "40" Then
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
        ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & x).Value = "45" Then
            Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}", True
            Application.SendKeys "~", True
    End If

Set GR = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("submit")
    GR(5).Click

'Wait for the Result to Load
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

Set CMRE = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("result")
    'MsgBox CMRE(0).innerText
    Range("F" & x).Value = CMRE(0).innerText

'Set NT = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("smcx-btn smcx-btn-secondary smcx-pull-left")
    'NT.Click

Next

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spent probably 3-4 hours looking into this. That website is devilish. I switched over to python and selenium. I was finally able to select the drop down options.

```
 dropDown = driver.find_element_by_id('dk_container_containerLoadType')
 dropDown.click()

 lis = dropDown.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
 conType = "20 FT"
 for li in lis:
    if li.text == conType:
        li.click()
```

however the website will not let you send keys directly to the input fields and then click the Get Rate button.

By clicking on the auto-complete option for the port origin or port destination it then puts a value that is associated with that port. As shown in  [Image of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHt4T.png). the value "50eb29010..." is what was generated by clicking on the suggested port destination.

Not sure what else to do...maybe send the keys and then incorporate mouse movement to click on that autocomplete option?
Not sure if this is all possible using just vba... If this is super important to you i can investigate more.